Get socket inode statistics
I want to know how much network my child process is using. I have my child process PID, socket inodes, ports, everything but I can't figure out how to get the network usage. The files at /proc/[pid]/net don't help. How can I do it programmatically?

In what way? Do you want to create a program or script? Bash, Python, or do you not have any preference?

@RobinHellmers using C++ but I can convert the solution is to my application in C++
